# Windows 8 Themes

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

While searching for a method to determine which theme is currently in use for Windows 8, I came across [this](http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_61.aspx) article.  It states that the theme is set per application and cannot be changed.  I didn't realize that this was the case, nor did I do anything to set my theme to "Dark" (although it seems to be so).  If this is correct, then how is the app theme set or, if not, how can I determine which theme is currently in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default new applications use the "Dark" theme, this is set by a property called RequestedTheme on the Application object. To change to the "Light" theme you can set the property in the App.xaml file on the Application element. You can read that same property to determine which theme isn't being used, but since it cannot be changed by the user it's value will only ever be what you set it to be.